# Can I delete a user in G Suite and reuse the user's email as new group email?

Tags: email, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I have a user called support@example.com in my G Suite. I want to change the email as group email. However I tried renaming to support-old@example, but turns out when I create the group, the email support@example.com cannot be used.

If I delete the user, can I reuse the email as the new group email right away?

Comment: Are you sure that you changed the email address instead of adding an alias? What's the textual error that you got?

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same situation. When you rename the email address, the popup says it adds the old email as an alias. You can check it if you click on the email account (in GSuite Admin), then open the User information section. There you can remove the alias, then create the group with the original name.

Keep in mind that the email name change can take up to 10 minutes to be fully effective.

I hope it helps somebody!